# SQL update query is not working in my Java program

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to update record in SQL database. So I wrote **Update** query in my program but it isn't working. I tried many solutions on Stack Overflow  like **con.commit()** and **con.setAutoCommit(false)**. I also added it into program but it isn't reflecting changes in database.

```html
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");
String de_pt = request.getParameter("department");
String cost_centercode = request.getParameter("costcentercode");
String doc_num = request.getParameter("documentnumber");   String doc_Name = request.getParameter("documentname");

...

String file_Name = "";
String folder_Name = "allfiles";
String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
            
            
if(request.getParameter("update") != null){
   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
      String sql = "update dmsfiles set firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where zid='"+z_id+"'"; 
      ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1,z_id);
      ps.setString(2,first_Name);
      ps.setString(3,last_Name);
      ps.setString(4,mail_i_d);
      ps.setString(5,d_iv);
      ps.setString(6,de_pt);
      ps.setString(7,cost_centercode);
      ps.setString(8,doc_num);
      ps.setString(9,doc_Name);
      
      ...
      
      ps.setString(22,file_Name);
      ps.setString(23,pa_th);
      ps.setTimestamp(24, null);
      int i = ps.executeUpdate();
      if(i > 0)
      {
      con.commit();
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
       //out.print("Record Updated Successfully");
        out.println("alert('Record Updated Successfully');");
      }
      else
      {
      //out.print("There is a problem in updating Record.");
      out.println("alert('There is a problem in updating Record.');");
      }
      }
      catch(SQLException sql)
      {
      request.setAttribute("error", sql);
      out.println(sql);
      }
      }
      %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>editprocess jsp Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: “Not working”means? Any exceptions thrown?

Comment: no error occurred. no exceptions occurred. Only Home button is displayed on screen.

Comment: do you have a row with specified z_id in the database ?

Comment: @akshayapandey Yes I have

Comment: what happens if you remove the if else statement and place the commits below `ps.executeUpdate();`?

Comment: @LV98 I tried as per you said. nothing changes happened.

Comment: please help me with this :(

Comment: @priyadhanba Never done Java, but for each layer of code like the `if` statements, I suggest you put a messagebox or message dialog I believe they are called in java for each `if` `else` statement. See where it stops and figure out why. Good luck!

Comment: could you print the query and check if that query is working if you fire it on DB

Comment: In your update query there are actually 23 parameter index but you are setting 24 paramterindex values in preparedStatement. And then remove your first statement "ps.setString(1,z_id)" because you already assigned a value in your sql where clause. And the last changes is once you get the connection object set the autocommit as false no need to set the after commit the transaction.

Comment: @GauravDhiman I tried query in DB it is executed successfully.

Comment: @priyadhanba if no exception is thrown than java much execute either if block or else block in both case  alert should be shown in UI. try put some breakpoints and debug your code

Comment: @MeetPatel no alerts is showing on screen when I execute

Comment: @SManikandan I removed "ps.setString(1,z_id)" and con.commit() then also nothing happened.

Comment: can you print the integer value of i in the console if i value equals to zero means that none of the rows has not been changed or else i value > 0 means that number of affeacted rows in your case can you log the value of i

Answer (score 0):

looking at comments i am assuming that your code is not executing thats why you dont have any error or alerts. one of the possible reason that `if(request.getParameter("update") != null)` will evaluate false .

check request has update parameter or not.

Comment: update button is added into edit.jsp. and In question that code is from editprocess.jsp. I have used update button from edit.jsp to editprocess.jsp

Comment: if(request.getParameter("update") != null) evaluate true or false ?

Comment: if(request.getParameter("update") != null) evaluates false

Comment: I got this exception :   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -19
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
 at org.netbeans.modules.editor.java.JavaCodeTemplateFilter$1$1.run(JavaCodeTemplateFilter.java:126)
 at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:609)
 at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:153)
 at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:137)

Comment: that means update parameter is not in request check in request if it is exits or not or sample request object

Comment: could you please explain what should I do now because I am not getting what are you saying :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207654/discussion-between-meet-patel-and-priya-dhanba).

Comment: when I execute then popup of exception generated